# JMS outbound channel adapter converting to byte[]

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using below config to send JMS message with an Object payload( lets say HelloWorld object) but when I receive message using Message driven adapater the payload is converted into byte[].

Is there a way to prevent this? I see outbound adapter eventually calls SimpleMessageConverter   method `createMessageForSerializable --> session.createObjectMessage(object)

```
<si:chain input-channel="errorChannelIn"> 
  <si:router 
       expression="headers.jms_redelivered.equals(T(java.lang.Boolean).FALSE) ? 'errorQueueChannel' : 'channel2Name' " 
       apply-sequence="true"> 
     <si:mapping value="errorQueueChannel" channel="errorChannel"/> 
     <si:mapping value="channel2Name" channel="channel2"/> 
  </si:router> 
</si:chain> 

<si-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorQueueMessageSender"
                                 channel="errorChannel"
                                 connection-factory="connectionFactory" session-transacted="true" destination="errorQueue"
        />
```

However, when I send message using JmsTemplate then it perfectly sends message as messageObject and message driven adapter picks up the Object as payload. Code snippet below.

Any idea where am I going wrong.

```
jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createObjectMessage(messageObject);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the `extract-payload="false"` on the `<si-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

In that case `<si-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` delegates work to the `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter` which ends up with:

```
else if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
    return extractSerializableFromMessage((ObjectMessage) message);
}
```

and you get deserialized `Message<?>`.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, it is really not clear what's going on. Just tested with our [Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jms). There you can find server/client configs: `outboundChannelAdapter.xml` and `inboundChannelAdapter.xml`. And I added a test-case to the `GatewayDemoTest`:

```
private final static String[] configFilesChannelAdapterDemo = {
        "/META-INF/spring/integration/common.xml",
        "/META-INF/spring/integration/inboundChannelAdapter.xml",
        "/META-INF/spring/integration/outboundChannelAdapter.xml"
};

@Test
public void testAdapterDemo() throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "testCase");

    final GenericXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext(configFilesChannelAdapterDemo);

    final MessageChannel stdinToJmsoutChannel = applicationContext.getBean("stdinToJmsoutChannel", MessageChannel.class);

    Foo foo = new Foo("bar");

    stdinToJmsoutChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(foo).build());

    final QueueChannel queueChannel = applicationContext.getBean("queueChannel", QueueChannel.class);

    Message<?> reply = queueChannel.receive(20000);
    Assert.assertNotNull(reply);
    Object out = reply.getPayload();

    Assert.assertThat(out, Matchers.instanceOf(Foo.class));

    Assert.assertEquals(foo, out);

    applicationContext.close();
}

public static class Foo implements Serializable {

    private final String bar;

    public Foo(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Foo foo = (Foo) o;

        return !(bar != null ? !bar.equals(foo.bar) : foo.bar != null);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return bar != null ? bar.hashCode() : 0;
    }

}
```

As you see I sand some `Serializable` object to the queue and the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` receives for me exactly the same deserialized object.

Maybe your issue is somewhere before the `<jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` where you may use a `<payload-serializing-transformer>`?

Would you mind rechecking the `payload` just before `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` or even putting break point to the `SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage` ?

Comment: Nah, I tried with extract-payload="false" and true both but did not work when i send message with payload of object.

 I have an object of class A as payload for outbound channel adapter and that is the payload I expect when message-driven adapter consumes message from queue rather than byte[]
This works fine when I put message on queue with jmsTemplate as mentioned in last part of my first message. Will add more details to original question if not clear. Thanks

Comment: Added test-case and some explanation

Comment: Thanks Artem. I did had breakpoints and can see that when a message is put on queue using `jms:outbound-channel-adapter` with payload as object ( example foo) then i get it as Object as I can see in `SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage` but byte[] when at `Object fromMessage(Message message)`

I will keep debugging

Comment: So, do you want to say, that `JmsTemplate` sends it as an `ObjectMessage`, but `<si-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` as a `BytesMessage`?

Comment: yep. Before This I have a a chain before that

`<si:chain input-channel="errorChannelIn">
        <si:router expression="headers.jms_redelivered.equals(T(java.lang.Boolean).FALSE) ? 'errorQueueChannel' : 'channel2Name' " apply-sequence="true">
            <si:mapping value="errorQueue" channel="errorChannel"/>
            <si:mapping value="channel2Name" channel="channel2"/>
        </si:router>
    </si:chain>
`

Comment: I see the typo in your `<router>` definition. You are expecting `errorQueueChannel`, but have mapped it as `errorQueue`. ???

Comment: Apologies just a type while posting comment here. No typo in actual config.

Comment: M-m-m. Is your JMS queue empty before the test?

Comment: Yes, it is empty and have tried when not empty as well.

Comment: Would you mind to simplify it somehow to help me to come up with a test-case to investigate what's going on. Thanks and sorry: now I don't see how to help you.